# Retrieve email preview using REST api

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api

I was trying to retrieve the "rendered" email using APIs.
Using the following call:
`https://www.exacttargetapis.com/guide/v1/emails/6701/dataExtension/key:6B9F561B-8324-4625-BE23-99DB74EA285A/contacts/key:0032600000afb32AAA/preview?kind=html`

I get this error:

```
    {
    "message": "Unable to generate preview.",
    "errorcode": 10006,
    "documentation": "",
    "validationErrors": [
        {
            "message": "Email::BuildMessage(string, int)- This method can only be called with a valid Email ID.",
            "errorcode": 10004,
            "documentation": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The email ID that i'm using exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. Using this API call the "emailID" is not the one shown by the UI, instead it uses the "legacyID" of the email asset.

I found it out using `%%_emailid%%` inside my email, which shows the "legacyID" of the email it is used in.

This ID can also be retrieved with the GET metod to see the asset details:

```
{{hostEndpoint}}/asset/v1/content/assets/{ID}
```